# Why does std::count passes constants to lambda, not chars when working on string?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a string and want to count for certain elements in it. I wrote a code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    int b = count(a.begin(), a.end(), [](char g) {return (g == '"' or g == '.' or g == ',' or g == ';' or g == ':' or g == '!' or g == '?');});
    cout << b;
}
```

Since std::count should return number of elements that are equal to another element (specified as third parameter of the function) or that meets certain function by passing elements one-by-one to that function, I expect it to pass chars to my lambda function. I wrote mostly as in last example on [CPPreference](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count), but looks like it works not in a way I expect it to be. During compilation I face a error in my lambda function:

> /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/predefined_ops.h:241:17:
>   error: invalid operands to binary expression ('char' and 'const
>   (lambda at /home/keddad/CLionProjects/olimp/main.cpp:12:39)')
>           { return *__it == _M_value; }

So looks like count passes some kind of constant to my little function, which is later tries to compare it with char (and drops error). How can I make my code work? How does std::count actually works?

Comment: you probably meant to use `std::count_if`

Comment: I've also tried to move lambda to separate function, but faced the same issue

Comment: `std::count` takes a pair of iterators and a value. `std::count_if` takes a pair of iterators and a predicate. You want the latter.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, you are right! But looks like it is still working in a strange way. For example, string "Hi, guys!" have 2 chars that meet lambda function, but code prints 1. What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: @biryulin04 `cin >> a` stops reading chars when whitespace occurs. So you entered "Hi," into `a`, if you want to read chars with whitespaces use `getline`.

Answer (score 10):

`std::count` takes three parameters: two iterators and a value to compare against.
So it's trying to compare the lambda to each character in the string.

`std::count_if` takes three parameters: two iterators and a "callable" to be called for each character in the string.

As @piotr-skotnicki said, I suspect you want to use `count_if`.

Comment: The compiler errors on this issue are really bad！